# Return another entity or DTO inside of a DTO

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, dto

So basically I am writing an API that uses a DTO, but I am having trouble returning another entity inside of the DTO.

Here is my DTO:

```
public class DirectoryDTO {

  String personFirstName;
  String personLastName;
  Hrper hrper;

  public DirectoryDTO(String personFirstName, String personLastName, Hrper hrper) {
    this.personFirstName = personFirstName;
    this.personLastName = personLastName;
    this.hrper = hrper;
   }
  // getters and setters
}
```

My service that uses a query:

```
public List<DirectoryDTO> getCustomDirectoryEntries(String department) {

  List<DirectoryDTO> directoryDTOS = em.createQuery(
        "select new dto.DirectoryDTO(" +
                "p.firstName, " +
                "p.lastName, " +
                "p.hrper " +
                ")  " +
                "  from Person p " 
                , DirectoryDTO.class)
        .getResultList();

  return directoryDTOS;
}
```

So basically this returns a list of directoryDTOs with all the information filled out EXCEPT for the Hrper entity that is joined to Person:

Returned data:

```
{
    "personFirstName": "John",
    "personLastName": "Doe",
    "hrper": null
}, ....
```

A couple of other things...

1) When I take out the DTO part in the query and just write the results to a list, I get data in Hrper meaning that my join isn't incorrect.

2) I have also tried replacing Hrper Hrper with a created HrperDTO HrperDto in my DirectoryDTO, but then my query won't run because it is looking for the DTO rather than just the entity

Comment: I don't know if any framework could do it properly for you, but to handle this pattern, I built a custom converter based on reflection; so basically, I fetch the main entity from database, explore its collections and for each explored entity (plus the main one, of course), I convert it to its DTO representation.

Comment: @HBo Thanks for the comment.  Is there an example of this anywhere?  I wouldn't even know where to start when it comes to a custom converter

Comment: I wish I could share it with you, but since it's been built for a client, I can't... If your entities are not too complicated, not too deep, and so on, you could do it by hand by building dedicated methods (`DirectoryDTO transformDirectoryToDTO(Directory d`)... And if reflection is what you're after, well, it's 'as easy' as exploring the fields  from a starting point, looking for annotations, these sorts of things...

Comment: I definitely understand, unfortunately most of the entities are pretty complicated - makes me question if we are going about this the right way in the first place. Of course that isn't up to me ;)

Comment: Depending on the frameworks available to you, you might get lucky; I know that Spring is a good candidate to do so

Answer (score 1):

I created [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) for exactly that use case. You essentially define DTOs for JPA entities as interfaces and apply them on a query. It supports mapping nested DTOs, collection etc., essentially everything you'd expect and on top of that, it will improve your query performance as it will generate queries fetching just the data that you actually require for the DTOs.

The entity views for you example could look like this

```
@EntityView(Directory.class)
interface DirectoryDTO {
  @Mapping("firstName")
  String getPersonFirstName();
  @Mapping("lastName")
  String getPersonLastName();
  HrperDto getHrper();
}

@EntityView(Hrper.class)
interface HrperDTO {
  // attributes of Hrper that you need
}
```

Querying could look like this

```
public List<DirectoryDTO> getCustomDirectoryEntries(String department) {
  List<DirectoryDTO> directoryDTOS = entityViewManager.applySetting(
    EntityViewSetting.create(DirectoryDTO.class),
    criteriaBuilderFactory.create(em, Person.class)
  ).getResultList();

  return directoryDTOS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't provide the entities so I can't test this, but this is a quick thing to try so hopefully I won't waste too much of your time if it doesn't work. Try explicitly telling JPA to load the related entity immediately by using the `JOIN FETCH` syntax. Try replacing `from Person p` with `from Person p join fetch p.hrpr h`.

Since `SELECT NEW` IIRC doesn't retrieve the full graph of the object unless you tell it to, you possibly don't even need the `fetch` keyword--this might work: `from Person p join p.hrpr h`.